# Inserting data in database inbetween specific date

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Candidate_info(Name,Age,Party,Symbol,Type_election,Region,Constituency,Segment) VALUES ('$cn', '$age', '$np', '$content','$radio','$region','$co','$as')";
```

I want to insert users in the database but only on today's date.**

Comment: where have you specified the date and where are you checking it?

Comment: that's what i want i don't know how to do that

Comment: If there is no date specified, how are you planning on checking it? you can't expect us to do your coding for you

Comment: Give more info about what actually you have and what you tried and what actually you want. And also error if any

Comment: paul im not asking to do my coding I just want a way HOW TO

Comment: @ShujaPatel it's the same thing if you haven't tried anything first.

Comment: got u SIr paul , justbaron

Comment: @ShujaPatel just make sure there is a date and check it with an if

Comment: Done Thank you Sir

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean you want to insert Current Date along with your other values 
you could choose either of fallowing based on your need:

1) Create an additional column and set the default value to TIMESTAMP (can also set for Auto update on update if needed) you can also push date from php to override by passing date("Y-m-d H:i:s")

2) insert with php date("Y-m-d") to a varchar or date type col (use date recomended)